# show that minimising the distance to approximated vector is equivalent to selecting features with the most variance

Tags: machine-learning, pca, least-squares, covariance, svd

First off, a little disclaimer: I am basing the question on my own interpretation of the problem. It's well possible that I am mistaken.

**Setup:**
We are given: feature vectors $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ with dimension $N$ such that $k \geq N$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i=0$;
 $N$ orthonormal basis vectors $v_i$ of dimension $N$.
We define approximated vectors $x'$ such that $x'_j = \sum_{i}^d v_i^T x_j v_i$
 where $j = 1,\ldots ,k$ and $0 < d < N$.

**Problem:**
Show that the following two methods are equivalent.

1. minimize the objective function $\sum_{i}^K \|x_i - x'_i\|^2$
2. maximize $\sum_{i}^d v_i^T S v_i$
   where $S$ is the covariance matrix of the vectors $x$

**Question:**
My understanding is that *method 1* minimizes the distance between vector $x$ and its approximation $x'$, and that *method 2* selects the features with the highest (co)variance.
As I am aware, the *eigenvector of the covariance matrix with the highest eigenvalue* indicates the axis of highest variance, and that, by implication, a line along that axis would be the *Least Squares* approximator for the data.
Therefore, I see how the methods are equivalent in theory, but I'm having trouble finding a mathematical/formal representation of this intuition based on the given expressions.

Answer (score 0):

at least for the trivial case, where the vectors *v* are rows of the unit Matrix, we can say that **method 1** selects the dimensions of *x* where the elements have the largest absolute values.
additionally assuming that the data was centered *(i.e. mean = 0)*, and considering the definition of variance $ \frac 1n \sum(x - \mu)^2$ we can see that **method 2** also selects the dimensions where elements have the largest absolute values